# Is it ok to simply cap off an unused 240v line in a junction box?

Tags: electrical

I have a hard-wired 240v appliance in the garage. A junction box contains the connection between the 8/2 feed from the panel and the 8/2 appliance leads. I am removing the appliance. Is it legal to simply cap off the supply wires and screw the junction box closed? My preference would be to install a 6-50R, but the breaker is only 40a, so that's not an option. Does the breaker in the panel need to be removed/disabled so that the wire isn't live?

California.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can simply cap off the wires safely and cover the box. The box must remain accessible though, meaning you can't bury it in the wall.

Second, you CAN install a 50A receptacle on that line if it is for a welder.

Comment: As an added precaution. Label the breaker in the panel (if it isn't already), and turn the breaker off.